# Accessing data through OnetoOne key in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two models connected using a OnetoOne Model key.

```
class Job_expectation(models.Model):
    SLAB_CHOICES = (
        ('H', 'Hourly'),
        ('W', 'Weekly'),
        ('M', 'Monthly'),
    )
    EMPLOYER_CHOICES = (
        ('I', 'Individual'),
        ('C', 'Corporate'),
    )
    TYPE_CHOICES=(
        ('P','Part time'),
        ('F','Full time'),
        ('I','Internship'),
        ('L','Freelancing'),
        )
    readytoworkas           =   models.OneToOneField(Readytoworkas)
    salary_slab             =   models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=SLAB_CHOICES,default='M')
    employer_type           =   models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=EMPLOYER_CHOICES,default='C')
    industry                =   models.ForeignKey(organization_sector)
    state                   =   models.ForeignKey(State, related_name="Preferred State of Work")
    city                    =   models.ForeignKey(City, related_name="Preferred City of Work")
    region                  =   models.ForeignKey(Region, related_name="Preferred Region of Work")
    shift_type              =   models.ManyToManyField(Slot_preference)
    job_type                =   models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=TYPE_CHOICES,default='F')
    min_salary              =   models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Minimum expected Salary")
    max_salary              =   models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Maximum expected Salary")
    negotiable              =   models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Is your salary negotiable?")`
```

---

```
class Readytoworkas (models.Model):
    employee_id     = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    readytoworkas   = models.ForeignKey(Jobs)`
```

The results of a query made on the Readytoworkas model is a list. With each element in the list, i want to access the corresponding entry in the Job_expectation table.

How to do it? This is what I am trying to do right now.

```
skilllist   = Readytoworkas.objects.filter(employee_id=employee)
      for i in skilllist:
        job_expect        =   Job_expectation.objects.get(readytoworkas=i)
        i.employer_type   =   job_expect.employer_type
        i.job_type        =   job_expect.job_type
        i.shift_type      =   job_expect.shift_type
        i.min_salary      =   job_expect.min_salary
        i.max_salary      =   job_expect.max_salary
        i.state           =   job_expect.state
        i.city            =   job_expect.city
        i.region          =   job_expect.region`
```

Comment: +1 for skilllist :-) When you want to ensure nobody will ever be able to write this word correctly

Comment: haha.. but you just did :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more simple, using 'related_name':

```
class Job_expectation(models.Model):
    readytoworkas  = models.OneToOneField(Readytoworkas, related_name='job_expectation')

skilllist   = Readytoworkas.objects.filter(employee_id=employee)
for i in skilllist:
    job_expect = i.job_expectation
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: tried this.. still some issue shows this error: self.related.model.DoesNotExist

Comment: it means that some of your instances of Readytoworkas class haven't related Job_expectation instances. You should catch it using try-except.

Comment: working. Thanks. it was not reading the related name which it does now